# Is a conic rationally equivalent to $2L$ for $L$ a line?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, schemes

Let C be a smooth conic inside a projective variety $X$ with ample class $H$. Since $C$ is smooth we have $C \cong \mathbb{P}^1$ and $\mathcal{O}(H)|_C \cong \mathcal{O}_C(2)$, where I think we interpret $\mathcal{O}_C(2)$ as $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2)$. Let $L$ be a "line" in $X$, i.e. a subscheme of $X$ with Hilbert polynomial $p_L(t)=1+t$. Note that $C$ will have Hilbert polynomial $p_C(t)=1+2t$.

My question is: do we have $C \sim_{\mathrm{rat}} L$ or $C \sim_{\mathrm{rat}} 2L $, where $\sim_{\mathrm{rat}}$ denotes rational equivalence (in the Chow ring)?

Since $C \cong \mathbb{P}^1$ and $\mathbb{P}^1$ is a line, is seems like we would have the former case for a smooth conic? But e.g. for the case of a reducible conic $C = L_1 \cup L_2$ where we have two distinct lines intersecting at a point, it seems like we would have $C \sim_{\mathrm{rat}} 2L$? Am I correct in both cases here, or should they both (smooth and reducible) rationally equivalent to $2L$?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you mean that $X$ is a surface (otherwise a curve on $X$ is not a divisor and it is meaningless to talk about its linear system). And what do you mean by the linear system $|L|$?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the comment, sorry, if I have an arbitrary projective variety $X$ I think what I'm interested in is rational equivalence. So what I should be asking is: do we have $C \sim_{\mathrm{rat}} 2L$ in all cases? (I'll update/correct the question)

Comment: Still, what is $L$?

Comment: I think when I say $L$ is a line I mean that $L$ is a subscheme of $X$ with Hilbert polynomial $p_L(t)=1+t$.

Comment: Different lines can have different classes in the Chow group. Think of the example of a quadric surface (with two different line classes) or of a cubic surface (with 27 line classes).

Comment: Take $X=\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$. It has two rulings, call them $h, k$. Then take $H=h+k$, $C=H$ (an irreducible member of $|H|$) is a conic and tale $L=h$ say. Then $L$ is aline but $C$ is not linearly equivalent to $2h$, since $C^2=2$, but $(2h)^2=0$.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense, I suppose to get anything concrete about what $C$ is rationally equivalent to, I need to be specific about what $X$ is. Thanks for your help @Sasha and @Mohan!